# How to add label to "file upload" input?

Tags: php, forms, cakephp

In my code I have something like this:

```
echo $this->Form->input('name');
echo $this->Form->input('app_code');
echo $this->Form->file('icon');
echo $this->Form->input('description');
```

And the form looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, the file input does not have a label like the other input text fields. How can I add one (without having to create the HTML manually)?

Comment: How did you add the labels for the other inputs?

Comment: Labels are added automagically by the `input` method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$this->Form->input('icon', array('label' => 'Your label', 'type' => 'file'));
```

[Relevant info from the book](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1398/options-label)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$this->Form->input` for various types. It defaults to text inputs, but will do much more.

```
echo $this->Form->input('icon', array('type' => 'file'));
```

There's [more information](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1390/Automagic-Form-Elements) in the cookbook.

Comment: Which version of CakePHP are you using?

Answer (score 0):

have a look at the api here http://api13.cakephp.org/class/form-helper#method-FormHelperinput it is bound to be helpful in the future.